# How to keep Google Map static images on a fluid/responsive dimensions

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have been googling about it a lot, but couldn't find any appreciable opinion over the same,

I need to incorporate a static google map image in a jQuery Mobile project, for building an app with phonegap. The map image has to fill the viewport almost completely. Question is how, as it will obviously be opened across different devices of different screen sizes. I have tried with the percentage approach, but that certainly doesn't work here.

I would like to get some guidance on keeping the layout for the google map static image in a fluid layout, in the simplest possible way (Please, if possible).

Thanks

Comment: Use this one 1)http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/map-geolocation/#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: @Ved I have been following it. I don't need a dynamic map, but a static map to be used as an image, rather background.

Answer (score 6):

load the largest image size you are going to need initially into a container e.g. size of 380 x 250

this will be position:relative with overflow hidden  and max size you need.

```
figre 
    {
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

then absolutely position the  using top & left  to position the image centrally inside the container.

e.g.

```
figure img
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 125px);
        left: calc(50% - 190px);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried to style Google Static Map to follow the Bootstrap by referring to this website
http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/365_google_maps/demo/index.html

#### index.html

```
<div class="col-sm-8 map-wrapper">
    <a target="_blank" class="map-container" href="LINK_TO_GOOGLE_MAP">
         <img src="YOUR_GOOGLE_STATIC_MAP_QUERY">
    </a>
</div>
```

#### css

```
a.map-container {
    display: block;
    background-image: url("YOUR_GOOGLE_STATIC_MAP_QUERY");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    line-height: 0;
}
.map-container img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The static map now is responsive on my website. I am not sure if it is applicable to you, but this is how I do it.

Comment: You don't even need the image tag inside the a tag, just specify a `height` on the `a.map-container` style. Keeping the image tag has 2 disadvantages: It causes two map loads (one for the a tag's background image and one for the img tag itself) and 2. it causes a momentary flash of the map on the screen (because the image opacity is set to 0 as soon as the image loads and then the background image appears - this causes a flash when I tested). But great and elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a intermediate plugin like Picturefill which will allow you to deliver an appropriate image to every user depending on a variety of conditions like screen size, viewport size, screen resolution, and more.

http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Usage:

```html
<picture>
 <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
 <source srcset="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:small|Mountain+View,CA&size=800x800&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE, http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:small|Mountain+View,CA&size=500x500&scale=2&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE 2x" media="(min-width: 800px)">
 <source srcset="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:small|Mountain+View,CA&size=300x300&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE, http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:small|Mountain+View,CA&size=300x300&scale=2&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE 2x">
 <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
 <img style="width:100%" srcset="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:small|Mountain+View,CA&size=800x300&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE, http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.386052,-122.083851&zoom=13&markers=size:small|Mountain+View,CA&size=300x300&scale=2&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE 2x" alt="Google Map">
</picture>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/picturefill/2.0.0/picturefill.min.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but here's another suggestion to simplify showing a single marker map that is centered. Perhaps best when used with &scale=2 for maps up to 1280 wide.

```
.your-static-map-container
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px; /* or whatever the height of your map is */
    }
.your-static-map-container img
    {
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; /* adjust with media queries for specific height */
    }
```